# How does Linux detect mime type?

Tags: filenames, mime-types, freedesktop

I have a PDF file with extension `.pdf`. If I remove `.pdf` - the file is still recognized as PDF file (`$ file sample` - output `sample: PDF document, version 1.4.`)

What is the mechanism of filetype detection in Linux? Windows uses file suffix. I know that there are mime types. Does all popular file formats  contain their mimetype in HEX code?

Comment: You mean "How does `file` ...?" not "How does Linux ...?"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The detection is done through [libmagic](http://linux.die.net/man/3/libmagic) which looks for specific byte sequences with [magic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_format#Magic_number).